# Where can I find machine readable transcribed text of the 2016 Presidential speeches and debates?

Tags: data-request, usa, government, nlp, politics

I'm looking for a machine-readable repository of transcribed Presidential debates and speeches from the 2016 general election. Structured data with a common format is desirable, as well as updates for the remaining speeches before the election.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Text from the speeches are available at the [UCSB Presidency](http://www.presidency.ucsb.edu/2016_election.php) website

[image]

Text from the [debates](http://www.presidency.ucsb.edu/debates.php) available as well.

Answer (score 3):

The GitHub repo **[2016-campaign](https://github.com/paigecm/2016-campaign)** contains

> campaign speeches given by Hillary Clinton and Donald Trump during the 2016 presidential campaign.
>
> [and] the text of the three presidential debates, separated by speaker, in the presidential-debates folder.

The repo owner will add speeches as the occur.

- [Speech catalog](https://github.com/paigecm/2016-campaign/blob/master/Clinton-Trump-campaign-speeches.csv)
- [Three debates](https://github.com/paigecm/2016-campaign/tree/master/presidential-debates)

[image]

([my source](https://twitter.com/paigecmorgan/status/790603829314195456))